# Are SVG height and width attributes needed when embeded via CSS

Tags: css, svg

I am including my svg file as a `background-image: url(pic.svg)`. I was wondering if the `height` and `width` attribute is needed?

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="275" height="47" viewBox="0 0 275 47">`

Would this cause any problems in some browsers? Or on mobile devices?

Comment: It will cause the image to be rendered differently. Whether that's a problem is up to you.

Comment: I usually define `background-size`, so it scales according to that. But I am not sure if it is better practice to let it "scale" via the set attributes first or just directly with CSS

Comment: it does work when I remove the attributes, at least on my desktop (Chrome)